# Emacs -- how to replace regexpresion with backslash

Tags: emacs, regex

I am using Emacs and I want to replace every ocurence of "\textbf{" with "{\bf". I tried almost all combinations, e.g.:

- replace-regexp RET "\\texbf{" RET "{\\bf"
- replace-regexp RET "\texbf{" RET "{\bf"
- replace-regexp RET "\\texbf{" RET "{\\bf"
- ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for regex. Use `replace-string`:

<kbd>M-x</kbd>`replace-string`<kbd>Enter</kbd>`\textbf{`<kbd>Enter</kbd>`{\bf`<kbd>Enter</kbd>

For `replace-regex`, use `\\textbf{` and `{\\bf`.

Comment: I have Emacs 27.2 and `\\textbf{` won't match "\textbf{" there. Although `isearch-forward-regexp` works with `\\textbf{`, `replace-regexp` just don't.

Comment: Works for me in 27.1.